# Smallest positive integer divisible by and having digit sum equal to some 3-digit number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, problem-solving, divisibility

> Let $p,q,r$ be distinct digits among $1,2,4,6,8$, and consider the integer $pqr = 100p + 10q + r$.  Let $N$ be the smallest positive integer that is divisible by $pqr$ and has digit sum equal to $pqr$. Find $N$.

I've trying to solve it, but cannot find any way to solve it unless use guess and check method. Can anybody show me the way, so I can understand the steps?
Thanks

Comment: You are supposed to also figure out what $pqr$ is?  Or there are different answers for different choices of $pqr$?

Comment: I forgot to add more details. I've just made several correction in my post.

Comment: So the digits $p,q,r$ _must be_ distinct from each other? (_E.g._, the number $666$ is not allowed.$\;\;$  >:)$\;\;$)

Comment: You might look at sequence A002998 in the OEIS (see http://oeis.org/A002998 ) and the reference given there.

Comment: So the digit sum of N is greater than 100, and you want N!?  Thats a really big number.

Comment: Thanks Robert Israel. but, I really want to know, how can we get the smallest integer from this case. For example, we want to find the smallest integer N that can divisible by 124 and have sum digit equal to 124. What must I do first?

Comment: @DanielV: Its likely much smaller than $\mathrm{TREE}(3)$ ([MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/93828/how-large-is-tree3)).  Even $G(4)$ ([Googology link](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Goodstein_sequence)).  So not _toooo_ big.

Comment: @akusaja: I've altered the formatting of your question a little bit, and tried to make it more clear.  Please ensure that it still asks your intended question.  If not, either try to edit it yourself, or respond in a comment about what is wrong with my interpretation.

Comment: For N = 124 the number is $299979999999988$ (found in a link of page referred to by Robert Israel above) and has those two blocks of consecutive 9's which maybe could be used on other cases. Easy to check digit sum 124, and that it's divisible by 124 can be done using maple or other long integer able programs.